# Same select works on console but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

this is getting me mad.
This is the code I'm using right now:

```
   <?php
//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect( "mysql.kit-series.net", "XXXXX", "XXXXXX", "kit_series_net" ) or die( "Error " . mysqli_error( $connection ) );
$connection->set_charset( "utf8" );

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$select = "SELECT ID FROM wp_qnnpx4_posts WHERE post_type='tvshows' AND post_title = '" . $nombre . "'";
$result = $connection->query( utf8_encode( $select ) );
$result = $result->fetch_assoc();
$id     = $result['ID'];
echo $select;
echo $id;

//close the db connection
mysqli_close( $connection );
```

- The result it's the expected if I use the select on console.
- The result it's the expected if I use the select in the PHP and the
  $nombre varible has no accents.
- The result it's the expected if I use
  the select in the console and the $nombre varible has accents.

Only when $nombre has accents and is used on the PHP file, the result isn't the expect, and it just return no results.

I printed the select in that case, put it on console, and it works. I dind't know what more to do.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by put it on console???

Comment: I don't think so you can execute PHP Code through Browser console..! :D

Comment: Have you set the character set to UTF-8 in your HTML header, like `<html><head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> ...`? If not, the character encoding of submitted values may not be UTF-8 and causing problems.

Comment: Database console MySQL from the PHPstorm.
And yes, the HTML is UTF-8, like I say, if I pick the $select variable, it's the expect.

Comment: But if you are already on UTF-8, then `utf8_encode()` will have an averse effect. Did you try without it? Also make sure your editor has saved the PHP file in UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot trincot, you are totally right, was too much focused trying to make all UTF-8 that I totally forgot about that encode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `utf8_encode` unless you are processing non-UTF8 strings. From your question and comments it turns out that you are completely on UTF8 (HTML, database, database connection, PHP file encoding), so calling `utf8_encode` is not only not necessary, it will have averse effects.

As said in an appreciated contribution to the [PHP docs on `utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php):

> If your text is not encoded in `ISO-8859-1`, you do not need this function. If your text is already in `UTF-8`, you do not need this function. In fact, applying this function to text that is not encoded in `ISO-8859-1` will most likely simply garble that text.

Comment: You are totally right, I was focused looking at $select and forgot about that encode. So stupid for my part.

Thanks for the response. ;)